# htaccess - install Symfony2 in subfolder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to deploy a symfony app to a subfolder of my root directory and I'm trying to figure out how to do it right. I'll just explain the situation. My root directory has a subfolder named `/private`, which contains a htaccess file that redirects to `/private/web/current/` (I'm deploying using capistrano).

### Folder structure

```
- ROOT/
---- private/
------- .htaccess (1)
------- current/
----------- web/
------------- app.php
------------- .htaccess (2)
```

### htaccess (1)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /private/current/web/ [L]
```

### htaccess (2)

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

     RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
 </IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

### Result

When I request `/private`, i get a **symfony error**:

```
No route found for "GET /private/"
```

When I request `/private/login` AND `/login`, i get a **browser error**:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /private/login was not found on this server.
```

Now symfony is routing from the root directory, but the root for the symfony project is actually /private. I'm a noob in deployment and htaccess rules, so is there anyone who can help me with this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: 404 Route not found is from symfony, so have you tried replacing "private" in the url you typed in the browser with an actual route?
Anyway please tell us which directory is the document root and what url you requested.

Comment: I updated the question with some examples.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first htaccess is the problem (the path after private needs to be appended to the new url). Try sth like

```
RewriteRule ^/private/?(.*) /private/app/web/$1
```

or (generated with http://www.htaccessredirect.net/)

```
RedirectMatch 301 /private(.*) /private/app/web/$1
```